# How can I reproduce a bean load order issue related to Spring Security?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, dependency-injection, javabeans

We're providing a company-internal libary for Spring Boot projects. This library contains two filters, `SpringMvcFilter` and `SpringSecurityFilter`.

`SpringMvcFilter` should be loaded by default. `SpringSecurityFilter` should be loaded when Spring Security is configured, but `SpringMvcFilter` should then be deactivated. The `SpringMvcFilter` is configured like this:

```java
@AutoConfiguration
public class SpringMvcConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = {"springSecurityFilterChain"})
    public Filter springMvcFilter() {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

The `SpringSecurityFilter` is configured as follows:

```java
public class SpringSecurityConfigurer extends AbstractHttpConfigurer<SpringSecurityConfigurer, HttpSecurity> {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity builder) {
        builder.addFilterBefore(new SpringSecurityFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

When Spring Security is configured, the `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotation should prevent the `SpringMvcFilter` from being loaded. This works for all customers but one, i.e. for said customers both filters are loaded and active, and I'm failing to reproduce this problem.

I setup a Spring Boot project (2.7.16) with Spring Security configured and added a dependency to a library that exposes three beans:

```java
@AutoConfiguration
public class CoolReuseBeans {

    @Bean("coolReuseIntBean")
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = {"springSecurityFilterChain"})
    public Integer beanInt() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Bean("coolReuseStringBean")
    @ConditionalOnBean(name = {"springSecurityFilterChain"})
    public String beanString() {
        return "5";
    }

    @Bean("coolReuseBooleanBean")
    public Boolean beanBoolean() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The Spring Security config is straight-forward:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                        .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/")).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

The application prints on start up whether the respective beans have been found or not:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    private  static ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        hasBean("springSecurityFilterChain");
        hasBean("coolReuseIntBean");
        hasBean("coolReuseStringBean");
        hasBean("coolReuseBooleanBean");
    }

    private static void hasBean(String name) {
        String[] allBeanNames = applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        System.out.println(String.format("Did find %s? %s", name, Arrays.stream(allBeanNames).anyMatch(x -> x.equals(name))));
    }
}
```

When starting the app, the following things are logged:

```
253: DEBUG 36231 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'springSecurityFilterChain'

366: DEBUG 36231 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'com.example.beans.CoolReuseBeans'
367: DEBUG 36231 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'coolReuseStringBean'
368: DEBUG 36231 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'coolReuseBooleanBean'

CoolReuseBeans#beanString matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (names: springSecurityFilterChain; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'springSecurityFilterChain' (OnBeanCondition)

CoolReuseBeans#beanInt:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: springSecurityFilterChain; SearchStrategy: all) found beans named springSecurityFilterChain (OnBeanCondition)


Did find springSecurityFilterChain? true
Did find coolReuseIntBean? false
Did find coolReuseStringBean? true
Did find coolReuseBooleanBean? true
```

This is still as I would have expected it. Since Spring Security is configured and the `springSecurityFilterChain` bean is loaded, the bean that depends on it is loaded, and the one that depends on `springSecurityFilterChain` being absent is not loaded.

When I comment out the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation and start the application the following is being logged:

```
366: DEBUG 37070 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'com.example.beans.CoolReuseBeans'
367: DEBUG 37070 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'coolReuseIntBean'
368: DEBUG 37070 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'coolReuseBooleanBean'

385: DEBUG 37070 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'springSecurityFilterChain'

CoolReuseBeans#beanInt matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: springSecurityFilterChain; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

CoolReuseBeans#beanString:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (names: springSecurityFilterChain; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans named springSecurityFilterChain (OnBeanCondition)

Did find springSecurityFilterChain? true
Did find coolReuseIntBean? true
Did find coolReuseStringBean? false
Did find coolReuseBooleanBean? true
```

This also works as expected with respect to which beans are loaded from my library. However, one thing that confuses me is that the `springSecurityFilterChain` bean is apparently still being loaded, even though Spring Security is configured, albeit after the other beans (that's probably why the result is still correct).

Beyond that, I'm out of ideas of how to reproduce the issue. A behavior that would explain the problem that one customer experiences would be that the `springSecurityFilterChain` is loaded after the `@AutoConfiguration` that contains the `SpringMvcFilter` bean is being processed. However, I cannot figure out a way to make this happen. Also it contradicts my understanding of `@AutoConfiguration`, namely that these are processed at the last point in Springs bean loading code.

If anyone has an idea what's going on here or what else I could try to reproduce this, I'd be happy to hear your input!

Comment: us explaining your single customers behavior is impossible without logs or a reproduce example demonstrating your problem. Also remember spring security is loaded as soon as it is on the classpath, it loads in its default configuration. Good luck

Comment: Are the conditions configured by Spring Security implemented by adding dependencies or by other means?

Comment: @Toerktumlare I‘m aware that not having access to the logs makes this very difficult to debug/understand. Unfortunately, I cannot post any logs due to compliance reasons.

Comment: @DingHao this turned out to be the right direction. Their app a depends on a lib b, which provides the spring security config, and lib b itself then depends on our lib. Once I reproduced this setup, I got the same error. When I pull the spring security config back on app-level, the issue goes away. I haven't found a way to force the right behavior in this setup, yet.

Comment: Specify CoolReuseBeans to be configured behind SecurityAutoConfiguration,
@AutoConfiguration(after=SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
public class CoolReuseBeans {
}

Comment: @DingHao thanks, this has indeed solved my problem! Do you want to add this as an answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Specify CoolReuseBeans to be configured behind SecurityAutoConfiguration,

```
@AutoConfiguration(after=SecurityAutoConfiguration.class) 
public class CoolReuseBeans { 
}
```